# Do we really need to create an app registration Azure AD to Azure AD B2C in communicating with other Identity providers?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Won't AAD B2C handle all the communication with the other IdP part. Why do we need to create an app registration in normal AAD for Open Id Connect.

I just wanted to learn about AAD and was confused about this matter and couldn't find any documents regarding this that would clarify my doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenID Connect requires a clientID, a secret key and a redirect URL on the "host".

That's part of the protocol.

Hence for federation with AAD, you need an app. registration to define these.

**Update**

If you are federating via OpenID Connect to another IDP, e.g. Facebook, then you do not need an app. registration in Azure AD.

Comment: Thanks! So for enabling Facebook as an Identity provider, you would not need Open ID Connect right?

Comment: @Goutham Facebook uses OAuth (which OpenID Connect is built on), you need a client ID and secret but they're provided by Facebook as it's their system you're using to authenticate/authorize the user. If your app is authenticating using B2C and B2C is then authenticating using Facebook, you'll still need to generate an app registration in B2C for your app.

Comment: @DaveD Sorry for not explaining correctly,but I get that the app should be registered in AAD B2C. But what I couldn't understand was whether the app registration in AAD (not B2C) was necessary for setting up Facebook as an IdP. Would it not be possible to just register the app in AAD B2C and Facebook and  then setting Facebook as an IdP?

Comment: Correct, see above.